# How to understand the purpose of this function ？

Tags: c, computer-science

```
bool isEqualOrBiggerUint32(uint32_t src, uint32_t dest)
{
    return (src - dest < 0x7fffffff);
}
```

I think this function is compare `dest` and `src`.
But, why we should use **0x7fffffff** in this function ? 
Thank you

Comment: `0x7fffffff` (2,147,483,647) is the biggest value for (signed) `int32_t`.

Comment: @Jarod42 src and dest are unsigned int, so this is a unsigned subtraction. 0x7fffffff can be convert to a unsigned int.

Comment: I find the name of the function and the parameters slightly confusing.

Comment: I "explain" `0x7fffffff`, not the formula ;-)

Comment: @Gerhardh I update it.

Comment: Did you write the function? It is overcomplicating and confusing something simple. From its name, why can't you `return src >= dest;` (or the other way round)? Why use a function at all?

Comment: Why would you name two parameters of a comparison function "src" and "dst"? That's very confusing.

Comment: This code is wrong (if we assume it's meant to do what the function name says). For example, if `src == 0xffffffff` and `dst == 0` then their difference would give 0xffffffff and the function would incorrectly return false.

Comment: @interjay That's true. So there's no making sense of this function. It would perhaps have made sense if the parameters were `int32_t` then converted to `uint32_t` internally or such.

Comment: @Lundin I suppose it can be useful for comparing numbers which can wrap (like TCP sequence numbers) and are expected to be close together. But in that case its name is misleading.

Comment: @interjay: I think arguments are wrong (or input range have (not shown/documented) prerequires).

Comment: @OP: So you ask the purpose of that function, not what is `0x7fffffff`.

Comment: I guess it is returning whether `src` is no more than 0x7fffffff "above" `dest` in a cyclical fashion. As presented, the code will not work if `int` is more than 32 bits wide or if `int` is less than 32 bits wide and `long` is more than 32 bits wide, but that can be fixed with an explicit type cast: `return ((uint32_t)(src - dest) < 0x7fffffff);`.

Answer (score 0):

0x7fffffff is just a compact hexadecimal representation for the decimal number 2147483647.

This function will just return True if expression (src - dest) is less than  0x7fffffff (which is 2147483647 in decimal representation). Else it will return False as the boolean value.